# Prevent iOS Springboard from Caching previous versions of screens

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, homescreen, springboard

We have an iOS app for which we've updated the UI and branding.

If we produce a test build of the new app, and run it over the existing app (i.e. upgrading it), it runs fine.

However, if we quickly press the home button to exit the app, and quickly go back in again, it shows a cached old copy of that screen while it's loading. This is jarring in our case, as the colours are completely changed in the new app.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Check whether Apple has cached your old app design as screenshot, used for launch animation. When app enters background, the screenshot is usually taken and stored. Try to place your splash screen on window before app enters background.

Comment: Hi @Basheer, thanks for the input. When the user runs the new app they will already see the new splash screen, on launch, before the app enters the background.

Comment: I thought the issue you are facing may be due to old snapshot taken by Apple. Did you try to locate the app snapshot?  The purpose of adding splash screen is to hide sensitive information before Apple takes snapshot of the app before entering background.

Comment: Thanks @Basheer. I think our problem is we already have existing versions of the app caching these old screens, and there's no way for us to tell the Springboard not to use these when users upgrade to the new app.